# Radiobutton and Checkbox to SQL database in android

Tags: android, sqlite, checkbox, radio-button

I'm working in Android Studio and I'm setting up a SQLite database in order to store the users data in order to show it again later. I figured out as to how to do it with simple TextEdits, but how do I do it for the Radio Button and CheckBoxes? In my program there is two Radio Buttons, one for yes and one for no. The Checkboxes' are just attached to a textstring which I want to showcase.

My DatabaseHelper looks like:

```
public class DatabaseHelper  extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Events.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "student_table";
public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
public static final String COL_2 = "TITLE";
public static final String COL_3 = "DATE";
public static final String COL_4 = "REMINDER";


public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1); //superclass (context, name, factory, version)
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    //
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME +" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, TITLE TEXT, DATE TEXT, REMINDER TEXT)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insertData(String title, String date, String reminder){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2, title);
    contentValues.put(COL_3, date);
    contentValues.put(COL_4, reminder);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    if(result == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
public Cursor getAllData(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_NAME, null);
    return res;
     }
}
```

and my MainActivity looks like:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
DatabaseHelper myDb;
EditText edittitle, editdate, editreminder;
Button btnAddData;
Button btnViewAll;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    edittitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_title);
    editdate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_date);
    editreminder = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_reminder);
    btnAddData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_add);
    btnViewAll = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_view);
    AddData();
    ViewAll();
}

public void AddData() {
    btnAddData.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(edittitle.getText().toString(),
                            editdate.getText().toString(),
                            editreminder.getText().toString());
                    if (isInserted = true)
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data NOT Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
    );
}

public void ViewAll() {
    btnViewAll.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Cursor res = myDb.getAllData();
                    if (res.getCount() == 0) {
                        //show message
                        showMessage("Error", "No data found");
                        return;
                    }

                    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                    while (res.moveToNext()) {
                        buffer.append("id :" + res.getString(0) + "\n");
                        buffer.append("title :" + res.getString(1) + "\n");
                        buffer.append("date :" + res.getString(2) + "\n");
                        buffer.append("reminder :" + res.getString(3) + "\n");
                    }

                    //show all data
                    showMessage("Data", buffer.toString());
                }
            }
    );
}

public void showMessage(String title, String Message) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(Message);
    builder.show();
}
}
```

Comment: Mind being more specific ?

Comment: Yea.  I will post some code as an example.  Are you looking to save whether or not the user has clicked a checkbox or used the switch?

Comment: Preferably the checkboxes is only for the ones which has been clicked, and the radio buttons is just for the one that has been clicked.

Comment: What's your actual question? What doesn't work?

Comment: My question is: how the Radio Button and the Checkboxes work with the SQL database. How does the code and the listeners have to be change in order to format the user inputed data from the checkboxes / radiobuttons. If that makes any sense.